# Keep the number and delete the rest of the lines using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

Please can someone help me with the the regular expression for the following.

I just want to keep the telephone number and detele the rest of the lines.

```
Name: Text here

DOB: Text here

Address: Text here

Tel: 1234 567890
```

**What I want**:

```
1234 567890
```

(without the "Tel")

Comment: Why not common replace "Tel: " by "" (empty string)? Do you really need regex replace?

Comment: I also want to delete all the other lines. (Name, DOB etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A.*Tel: ([\d\h]+)|.*?`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A              # beginning of file
    .*              # 0 or more any character
    Tel:            # literally
    ([\d\h]+)       # group 1, 1 or more digit or space
  |               # OR
    .*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1, the phone number
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Won't this leave the digits in DOB and address?

Comment: @EduardoBissi: Good catch, you're wright, I'll find a fix, give me a minute

Comment: @EduardoBissi: Done.

Comment: Thanks guys, works well.

Comment: @Frank: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)